# Call Method from Controller without reloading the View?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How can I call a method on "@Html.ActionLink"-click with a parameter from a View without reloading the View? I'm working with ASP.Net MVC. I guess, i have to work with AJAX, but I don't know how it works.

This is my Code now: view:

```
@foreach (var p in Model.PresentedPresentations)
{                 
     @Html.ActionLink(" ", "AddPositiveRatingToPresentation", Presentation", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down", @id ="posRat"}}, new { presentationId = p.Id }) @p.PositiveRatings  
}
```

Controller:

```
public void AddPositiveRatingToPresentation(int presentationId)
    {
        if (presentationId == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("ungültige presID");
        }
        var presentationService = new PresentationService();
        presentationService.AddPositiveRating(presentationId);
    }
```

Comment: You need to use ajax to make a call to the server if you do not want to leave the page

Comment: Can you show me, how I can make a ajax request, because I found not the right request in the internet @StephenMuecke

Comment: Seriously? [google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mvc+how+to+make+an+ajax+request&oq=mvc+how+to+make+an+ajax+request&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64.8586j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should give you some idea how [AJAX](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc) is implemented.

**HTML:**

```
@foreach (var p in Model.PresentedPresentations)
{                 
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down",id ="posRat", data-presentation = p.Id />  
     @p.PositiveRatings  
}
```

---

**JQUERY:**

```
function AddPositiveRatingToPresentation(_this)
{
   //Get presentation Id
   var _presentationId = $(_this).data('presentation');

   //Create AJAX request
   $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("AddPositiveRatingToPresentation")',
             type: 'GET',
             cache: false,
             data: { presentationId: _presentationId  },
             success: function (data) {
                        //Code goes here
                    }
         });
}
```